# How to call web api Controller method with two parameters using angularjs

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am pretty new in angularjs and I've looked around to try to find some posts on this and there are many but none that address my specific question (that I could find).

It is as simple as that, I want to send two parameters through angularjs ($http POST) where my first parameter is a json of class object and second is int. What I tried :

```
        var url = '../Request/'+ id;
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: Data
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            debug.error(data);
            deferred.reject('An error occured while saving the request');
        });
```

In my web api Controller I have :

```
    [POST("Request/{id}")]
    public bool SaveRequest(Data data, int id)
    {
       ...
       ...   
    }
```

When I send only Data it works for me but when I tried to add Id and Data both it won't work. Please let me know what needs to be done for the same, Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried using `[FromBody]` attribute like this

```
 [POST("Request/{id}")]
 public bool SaveRequest([FromBody] Data data,[FromUrl] int id)
 {
      ...
```

More info on parameter [binding](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)